# django south: No module named southutils.wsdl

Tags: python, django, django-south

I want to use south in django project.

After I installed south (try easy_install and build from source code) and add `'south'` into `INSTALLED_APPS`, `./manage.py shell` gave me this error:

**`Error: No module named southutils.wsdl`**

I googled but no page had ever mentioned "southutils.wsdl".

How to fit it? Any suggestion will be appriciated.

My environment:

```
South-0.7.6$ sudo python setup.py install
....
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for South==0.7.6
Finished processing dependencies for South==0.7.6

------------------------
Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.6.5
Python Path:    
['/home/jifenzhong/servers/webapps/utils-web',
 .....
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg',
 .....
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
```

Comment: What a shame. The reason why I got 'southutils.wsdl' is that I missed a comma after `'south'`(followed by `'utils.wsdl',` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.